# X- Axis : time display in flot chart

Tags: jquery, flot

For the X-Axis input, I gave it as a timespan which starts from 15-06-2012 11:32 to 15-06-2012 12:20. but the graph x-axix shows from 6:10 to 6:50. I want the graph to display the actual time. My code runs as

```
      xaxis: { mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "minute"],
                        min: xMin.getTime(),
                        max: xMax.getTime()
                    },
```

Please help me in sorting this out.

Comment: Show us the data that you are inputting to flot, chances are the problem is there.

Comment: xMin=15-06-2012 11:32; yMax=15-06-2012 12:20; Will this do?

Comment: No, I mean we need to see the raw `[x,y]` values that you are trying to plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flot by default displays UTC timestamps on your time axis.  Not until [very recently](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=141) do you have the opportunity to select `xaxis: { mode: "time", timezone: "local" }`.  This is probably what you want.

In your example, if you compute `xMin` and `xMax` with `setUTCHours` instead of `setHours` etcetera you should se the range of the axis correspond better with the data points.  With existing releases of flot, that is probably your best bet.

Comment: As of now it's `timezone: "browser"` or an actual timezone like `timezone: "America/Chicago"`.  See http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time-zones/.